# Prevent word-break when converting text to image using DynamicDrawableSpan

Tags: java, android, spannablestring, spannable

I'm trying to convert text to an image by changing each character of this text to an image, but I faced the word-break issue, I would like to make it return to a new line

e.g :

[image]

Should be :

**Do it for**

**the**

**Aesthetic**

Here's my code :

**MyDynamicDrawableSpan class** :

```
public class MyDynamicDrawableSpan extends DynamicDrawableSpan {

    private final Context mContext;
    private final Drawable drawable;

    public MyDynamicDrawableSpan(Context context, Drawable drawable) {
        mContext = context;
        this.drawable = drawable;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable() {
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
        return drawable;
    }
}
```

**The necessary methods:**

```
public void insert(String text, int start, int end, Drawable drawable) {
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
    MyDynamicDrawableSpan spannable = new MyDynamicDrawableSpan(getApplicationContext(), drawable);
    message.setSpan(spannable, start, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
}


private void insertImageSpan(String str) throws IOException {
    addText(generateRansomNotText(str));
}

private void addText(SpannableString generateRansomNotText) {
    textView.setText(generateRansomNotText);
}



public SpannableString generateRansomNotText(String text) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        Drawable drawable = getLetterDrawable(getApplicationContext(), "" + text.charAt(i));
        String str = "" + text.charAt(i);
        insert(str, i, text.length(), resize(drawable));
    }
    return message;
}

private Drawable resize(Drawable image) {
    int width = image.getIntrinsicWidth() > 40 ? image.getIntrinsicWidth() : min_size;
    int height = image.getIntrinsicHeight() > 40 ? image.getIntrinsicHeight() : min_size;
    return ImageUtils.bitmap2Drawable(ImageUtils.scale(ImageUtils.drawable2Bitmap(image), width * multiple, height * multiple, false));
}
```

I tried to put : `android:hyphenationFrequency="none"` to the `TextView`, but it does not work

Comment: I doubt there's a way to do this. One solution would be to build a single image for each word and use it for the span instead of individual letters.

Comment: @Nicolas Thank you so much for this idea, I think I can achieve this